# How to access the response of a scenario from a different scenario?

Tags: karate

I have a feature file Product.feature .I have two Scenarios Create Product and Update Product. I have created a product in Scenario :Create Product. In the following scenario(Scenario :Update Product) I want to update the details of the product created in the Scenario : Create Product using the account id which will be in the response of the Scenario :Create Product .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to merge the `Scenario`-s into one. It looks like you have mis-understood how they have to be used. This is explained clearly in the [documentation](https://github.com/intuit/karate#script-structure):

> Variables set using `def` in the Background will be re-set before
>   every Scenario. If you are looking for a way to do something only once
>   per Feature, take a look at `callonce`. On the other hand, if you are
>   expecting a variable in the `Background` to be modified by one
>   `Scenario` so that later ones can see the updated value - that is not
>   how you should think of them, and you should combine your 'flow' into
>   one scenario. Keep in mind that you should be able to comment-out a
>   `Scenario` or skip some via tags without impacting any others.